# How to plot an arc of a circular crown [2D] on matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, geometry

What is an orthodox way to plot a circular crown [2D] first of all, I don't want to extrude a disk inside another disk because I needed it to be integrate in an animation.
Don't know if I can achieve the same thing but with a rectangular shaped bended plot.
[2D Circular Crown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCf5m.png)

Comment: Updated the thread

Comment: So, what did you try?

Comment: Maybe you are referring to matplotlib's `Wedge`? See the [tutorial example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/shapes_and_collections/patch_collection.html), where it seems to be called a ring, or a ring sector.